# $[a,b]$ compact proof

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

[image]

I am trying to show that $a \in A$

I understand that the green underline implies that {$a$} $\displaystyle \subseteq \bigcup_{\alpha} A_{\alpha}$ however this is not an arbitrary open cover of {$a$} but of $[a,b]$, there will be open coverings of {$a$} that do not cover $[a,b]$. I'm finding this rather confusing.

Comment: Use the Heine-Borel theorem.

Comment: @AdamHughes Use the Heine-Borel theorem in a proof of the Heine-Borel theorem?

Comment: @bof the HB thm is stronger than this.

Comment: If we can use HB theorem then what in the world do we need this proof for?

Comment: @Timbuc who knows, but certainly it's the easiest way to do it, and if the op doesn't provide enough context, there's no reason to believe it's out of bounds. Doing it using actual open covers is cumbersome.

Comment: @AdamHughes I agree with you, yet perhaps this exercise is designed to give some sweaty work to students.

Comment: @Timbuc What do you think of my suggestion for altering how A s defined? It is at the bottom of our discussion earlier

Comment: @usainlightning I really can't see any way out of this long discussion if you don't accept my definition of $\;A\;$ and see how it works. Sorry.

Comment: Apologies if I am  being annoying. All I need to know is whether or not I misread the definition of $A$ originally and it should have been stated as I have done at the bottom of the page. The rest of the proof provided in the notes relies on this being true.

Answer (score 2):

We could argue as follows:

$$\;(*)\;\;[a,b]\subset\bigcup_{\alpha\in I}A_\alpha\implies \;\exists\alpha_0\in I\;\;s.t.\;\;a\in A_{\alpha_0}\implies \{a\}=[a,a]\subset A_{\alpha_0}\implies a\in A$$

since clearly $\;A_{\alpha_0}\;$ is a finite subfamily of $\;X:=\{A_\alpha\;:\;\;\alpha\in I\}\;$ (which, btw, I think should be the *actual* definition of $\;A\;$ instead of what you wrote).

Also observe we don't need at all that $\;\{a\}=[a,a]\;$ is compact, but only we do need  (*) above .

Comment: How do we know that $A_{\alpha_0}$ is a (finite) subcover of {${A_\alpha}$}$_\alpha$, where {${A_\alpha}$}$_\alpha$ is a covering of $[a,b]$?

Comment: $A_{\alpha_0}$ does not cover $[a,b]$

Comment: @usainlightning I didn't claim it does. Please read what the OP wanted and what I claim to have proved.

Comment: I am the OP. For $a \in A$, $a$ must belong to the union of a finite subcover of {$A_\alpha$}$_\alpha$. But $A_{\alpha_0}
$ is not a finite subcover for {$A_\alpha$}$_\alpha$?

Comment: @usainlightning If that's really your definition of $\;A\;$ then it makes not much sense, as **if** there's already a finite subcover of $\;[a,b]\;$ for you to define $\;A\,$, then your proof is already done, isn't it? And by "finite subcover" I understand "a finite subcover of the whole interval $\;[a,b]$"

Comment: I don't understand, I just repeated the definition provided in my original post.

Comment: @usainlightning I know, but either you misunderstood it or else it just doesn't make much sense: if we need a finite subcover (of the whole interval) in order to be able to define $\;A\;$ , then either there's nothing to prove, as we **already** have afinite subcover!, or else the definition is pointless. I think it is this last option and one should understand/define clearly what $\;A\;$ is, and imo it should be what I wrote as a comment below your new question in the site.

Comment: So what you're saying is that because we need a finite subcover of {$A_\alpha$}$_\alpha$ in order to define $A$ then $[a,b]$ has a finite subcover for all open coverings and hence is compact?

Comment: @usainlightning No. What I'm saying is that **if** that is *really* the definition of $\;A\;$ then we **already need to know** $\;[a,b]\;$ is compact and thus that we have a finite subcover of it from $\;\{A_\alpha\}\;$ in order to be able to define $\;A\;$ , which of course is absurd. I'd rather think that the meaning of "finite subcover" in the definition of $\;A\;$ means in fact "a union of a finite number of element of $\;\{A_\alpha\}\;$", or in other words: $$A:=\left\{\;x\in[a,b]\;:\;\;[a,x]\subset \bigcup_{\alpha\in J}A_\alpha\;\right\}\;,\;\text{with}\;\;|J|<\infty$$

Comment: I think I am saying the same thing as you? What is different?

Comment: @usainlightning When you have "a(n open) cover" $\;\{A_\alpha\;:\;\;\alpha\in I\}\;$ of a topological space, "a subcover" usually means $\;\{A_\alpha\;:\;\;\alpha\in J\subset I\}\;$ **that still covers the whole space** .

Comment: That is how it has been defined for me as well. I'll have another go: From the definition of $A$ for an arbitrary open covering of $[a,b]$, {$A_\alpha$}$_{\alpha}$ , there exists a finite subcover. Hence $[a,b]$ is compact.

Comment: @usainlightning So *because you* give a nonsensical definition of $\;A\;$ , then Q.E.D. ?! I think anyone could find that absurd. Either you re-define in a logical way $\;A\;$ or else you dispose of it completely, but you cannot even attempt to carry on a proof that way, imo.

Comment: What if the finite subcover was only defined for $[a,x]$? As if {$A_\alpha$}$_{\alpha}$ is an open covering for $[a,b]$ it is also an open covering for $[a,x]$.